# Ansible loop over range of letters in template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to generate an Ansible template that increments on letters alphabetically rather than numbers.  Is there a function similar to `range(x)` that could help me?

pseudo code example

```
{% for letter in range(a, d) %}
{{ letter }}
{% endfor %}
```

expected output

```
a
b
c
d
```

Alternatively is there a way to convert a number into it's alphabetical equivalent in Ansible?

```
{% for i in range(6) %}
{{ convert(i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### UPDATE

For those who are curious, here's how I ended up applying @zigam's solution.  The goal was to create xml tags with every host from a hostgroup.

In my role defaults:

```
ids: "ABCDEFGHIGJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

In my template:

```
{% for host in groups['some_group'] %}
<host-id="{{ ids[loop.index] }}" hostName="{{ host }}" port="8888" />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over a string:

```
 {% for letter in 'abcd' %}
 {{ letter }}
 {% endfor %}
```

If you want to iterate over a range of the alphabet:

```
 {% set letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' %}
 {% for letter in letters[:6] %} {# first 6 chars #}
 {{ letter }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The second option is more in line with what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom filter plugin to do what you want

in filter_plugins/scratch_filter.py:

```
def scratch_filter(n):
    return chr(n)

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Number to Character filter '''
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'scratch_filter': scratch_filter
        }
```

in scratch-template.j2:

```
{% for x in range(101, 113) %}
    {{ x|scratch_filter }}
{% endfor %}
```

in scratch_playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: test loop
    template: 
      src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scratch-template.j2"
      dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scratch-template-output.txt"
```