# How to output the letters a to z with ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I hope to get the letters a to z in the easiest way.
Instead of manually typing a to z, then set a variable and loop it.

There are 22 disks in my system. Theirs is /dev/sda to /dev/sdw.
I want to use the ansible-playbook to partition and format them in turn. So I want to get the letter a-w as a variable operation.

```
---

- hosts: hadoop
  vars:
    test: [a, b, c, d]

  tasks:
  - parted:
      device: "/dev/sd{{ item }}"
      number: 1
      state: present
    with_items:
    - "{{ test }}"
```

so look that good, but not smart.

Comment: Why'd you need ansible for that? A simple shell script would do.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and how it failed. Please read [ask] page!! Also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible loop over range of letters in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974291/ansible-loop-over-range-of-letters-in-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the letters of the alphabet. Just use the `find` module to find disk devices matching the pattern `sd[a-z]`.  For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: get available devices
      find:
        paths: /dev
        patterns: "sd[a-z]"
        file_type: any
      register: disks

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ disks.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

On my system, this outputs:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sdc) => {
    "msg": "/dev/sdc"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sdb) => {
    "msg": "/dev/sdb"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sda) => {
    "msg": "/dev/sda"
}
```